# Where to keep mapping logic from API to reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm getting the following request from the backend:

```
{
  total: 2,
  items: [...]
}
```

I want to save it to the following reducer:

```
{
  value: [...] // items
  total: 2,
  fetching: false,
  error: false
}
```

So, I'm dispatching some action with the raw request:

```
dispatch(someAction(rawRequest));
```

The action does the remapping:

```
export const someAction = payload => ({
  type: "SOME_TYPE",
  payload: {
    total: payload.total,
    value: payload.items,
    fetching: false,
    error: false
  }
});
```

And the reduces just pushes it to the state. My question is - is this a good practice to do what I did, or is it better to do all the mappings inside the reducer, and make actions just plain simple objects?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are doing is perfectly fine. Your reducer does not need to be tied to the response format of an api. Doing something in an action creator (or a middleware if it's a common enough pattern; not necessary here) that makes it easier for your reducers to consume the action makes good sense to me.

In this case, it also gives you some protection from api changes. You would potentially only need to modify the action creator rather than every reducer that consumes the action.

Comment: Yep. [As I said in a recent tweet](https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/843150523905855488), "it's often good to do normalization in an action creator (or middleware, or saga, etc), because then the reducer doesn't care about the API endpoint behavior".